# How does the Google camera app save photos without asking for a storage permission?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, storage

The official Google camera app (https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/CameraXBasic) does not ask for any storage permissions. So, how does it save the photos to the device? just look at the AndroidManifest.xml file: https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml As you can see, it does not ask for that storage permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at their [`getOutputDirectory` method](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/MainActivity.kt#L84):

```
fun getOutputDirectory(context: Context): File {
    val appContext = context.applicationContext
    val mediaDir = context.externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
        File(it, appContext.resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() } }
    return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
        mediaDir else appContext.filesDir
}
```

They are using [`getExternalMediaDirs()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalMediaDirs()) and, if none are available (which isn't ever the case in reality), [`getFilesDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()) and both of those methods specifically mention in their documentation:

> No additional permissions are required for the calling app to read or write files under the returned path.